# Capture strings between groups with groups aren't fixed (RegEx)

Tags: python, regex

I'm trying to capture a group of strings between two groups of strings. The RegEx is mostly working, but it doesn't capture all when there is a change in pattern.

The string is:

```
2023-03-20 / 10:56:58 4737 Security-Enabled Global Group Modified 73 high SRVDC2 john.smi.admin 10.7.3.252 1
```

After the date and time is a four-digit number, which sometimes is not present, so the log show N/A instead. That's when I'm having trouble. The RegEx must be able to capture both the four-digit number and the N/A message.

Here's what I've tried:

```
import re
string = '2023-03-20 / 10:56:58 4737 Security-Enabled Global Group Modified 73 high SRVDC2 john.smi.admin 10.7.3.252 1'
pattern = '(?<=\d{4} )(.*?)(?=\s\d{2}\s)'
res = re.findall(pattern,string,re.MULTILINE)
print(res)
```

Comment: What is shown by the `print(res)` in the updated question? What should it show?

Comment: "The RegEx must be able to capture both the four-digit number and the N/A message." Why not just... use two regexes, and combine the results?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `'(?<=\d{4} | N/A )(.*?)(?=\s\d{2}\s)'` instead.

It looks behind to 4 digits and space OR `N/A` between spaces. This is needed to keep lookbehind group fixed length.

Comment: @user21447606, you should accept one of the answers. It has a [reputation bonus](https://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation) for author and you.

Answer (score 2):

You can combine two lookbehinds with `|` (or).

```py
pattern = r'(?:(?<=\d{4} )|(?<=N/A ))(.*?)(?=\s\d{2}\s)'
```

Answer (score 1):

You don't have to use any lookarounds, you can match and then use the capture group 1 value:

```
\b(?:\d{4}|N/A)\s+(.*?)\s+\d\d\s
```

**Explanation**

- `\b` A word boundary to prevent a partial word match
- `(?:\d{4}|N/A)` Match either 4 digits or `N/A`
- `\s+` Match 1+ whitespace chars
- `(.*?)` Capture **group 1**, match any character except a newline as few as possible
- `\s+\d\d\s` Match 1+ whitespace chars, 2 digits and a single whitespace char

See a [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/nOTx0m/1)